# If I use GA3 and GA4 in parallel do I have to include both scripts in the header?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are using GA3 and have included the tag in the header in the standard way like this:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-10', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

Now we also want to use GA4.

Do I have to include both code snippets in the header at the same time with GA4 like this:

````
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-1234567890"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-10', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
  gtag('config', 'G-123456789');
</script>
```

Or can it be managed by TagManager?
````

Comment: Not really. In GTM there will be separate tag or variable to do this. But it's still better to control all of these in GTM.

Comment: Thank you.
I have removed the GA4 tag: gtag('config', 'G-123456789');
And have created in GTM a tag with the measurementID of GA4.
I guess that is the way to go.
Still I wonder if I have to set up the GA3 tag in the scripts. I guess I can also move it to GTM and just have the GTM code snippet on the website, right?

Comment: Exactly. You can also move UA pageview tracking to GTM and include GTM snippet in your website source code. So in your website source code you will have only the GTM script and inside GTM you will have different tags for UA and GA4 tracking.